# PHP how to check the checkbox by using if else condition within echo?

Tags: php

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="OMG" checked>';
```

this way will display a normal checkbox with checked. My question is that is it possible to put a if else inside the checkbox?

For example,

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="OMG" "if(2>1){ echo "checked";};" >';
```

The reason i want to do this is because I have a array with 6 data, if certain condition meet, the checkbox will be checked. If the echo method i mentioned above is invalid, so what's the correct way of doing that?

```
$zzz[1]="western food";
$zzz[2]="chinese food";
$zzz[3]="mix food";
$zzz[4]="japanese food";
$zzz[5]="korean food";
$zzz[6]="italian food";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily by concatenating your string with a ternary operator:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="OMG" ' . ((2>1) ? "checked" : ""). '>';
```

The ternary operator works this way:

```
(2>1) ? 'checked' : ''
```

2>1 is considered a boolean expression (that returns either true or false). 'checked' is the result in case the boolean expression is true, and an empty string '' if it is false.

Comment: the output is "checked"  . any example that is the checkbox being checked after the if condition meet?

Comment: @gosulove Check it out now :)

Answer (score 1):

Corrected version of your code

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="OMG" '.(2>1)?"checked":"".' >';
```